# Check if in a specific position

Tags: pine-script

This will solve a more complicated problem I am having.

I have two lines in my code:

```
strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true, when = upAllConditions, stop = upStopLoss)
strategy.entry(id = "Short", long = true, when = upAllConditions, stop = upStopLoss)
```

I can't seem to figure out how check to see if I am in one of those positions.

I do NOT want to go short if I am in a "Long" position, and do NOT want to go long if I am in the "Short" position.

(the more complicated problem is I actually want to use a different stop loss value depending on which position I am in, hence the need to check. seemed like this was an easier way to ask)

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in variable [strategy.position_size](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_size):

> Direction and size of the current market position. If the value is > 0, the market position is long. If the value is < 0, the market position is short. The absolute value is the number of contracts/shares/lots/units in trade (position size).

Comment: kuznet1, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should carry the position's status through the history in the next way:

```
IN_SHORT = 1
IN_LONG = 2
NONE = 3

status = NONE
status := nz(status[1], NONE)

if status != IN_SHORT and upAllConditions
    strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true, when = upAllConditions, stop = upStopLoss)
    status = IN_LONG
```

Comment: it should work, if you mean using this approach in a strategy. Or what exactly do you mean would it work in indicator?